# Determine how many key values have changed in an object

Tags: javascript, lodash, javascript-objects

I have two of the same objects to compare, with different data types as object props (array and object).

I want to know how many properties are different than the first one. See example below:

```
OriginalObject = {
 names : [],
 numbers : [],
 dates :{
  from: null,
  to : null,
 },
 other :{
  from: null,
  to : null,
 },
}

ModifiedObject = {
 names : ['Steven', 'Judy'],
 numbers : [1,5,7],
 dates :{
  from: 15152112512,
  to : null,
 },
 other :{
  from: null,
  to : null,
 },
}
```

Since names, numbers, and dates changed, desired output is: 3

I was thinking perhaps I could iterate over the object properties and use _.isEqual of lodash, but I would like to know if there is an easy and shorthanded version to do achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a solution using lodash, you could apply [`_.toPairs()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#toPairs) on both of your objects. Then use [`_.differenceWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith) to compare the obtained arrays and finally get the length of the comparison array :

```js
OriginalObject = {
 names : [],
 numbers : [],
 dates :{
  from: null,
  to : null,
 },
 other :{
  from: null,
  to : null,
 },
}

ModifiedObject = {
 names : ['Steven', 'Judy'],
 numbers : [1,5,7],
 dates :{
  from: 15152112512,
  to : null,
 },
 other :{
  from: null,
  to : null,
 },
}

console.log(_.differenceWith(_.toPairs(OriginalObject), _.toPairs(ModifiedObject), _.isEqual).length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this as a solution.

```
 appliedFiltersCount (state) {
        let changedCount = 0
        Object.keys(state.filters).forEach((field) => {
          if (field in state.filters && field in getDefaultState().filters) {
            if (!isEqual(state.filters[field], getDefaultState().filters[field])) {
              changedCount++
            }
          }
        })
        return changedCount
 },
```